# How many users can be in a AD LDS group?

Tags: users, groups, ad-lds

Microsoft published the recommended [maximum limits for users in an Active Directory group](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/active-directory-maximum-limits-scalability%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_Users). It basically says :

> Starting with Windows Server 2003, the ability to replicate discrete changes to linked multivalued properties was introduced as a technology called Linked Value Replication (LVR).

and

> This allows the number of group memberships to exceed the former recommended limit of 5,000 for Windows 2000 or Windows Server 2003 at a forest functional level of Windows 2000.

Given the replication meta data below, can anybody tell me what is the maximum number of users a AD-LDS group can hold ?

```
Getting 'CN=Member,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,CN={67B333FE-ADB4-430D-AAEE-D4CCE4B98A2E}' metadata...
23 entries.
 AttID     Ver   Loc.USN                      Originating DSA            Org.USN         Org.Time/Date
 =====     ===   =======                      ===============        =======         =============
     0       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
     3       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 20001       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 20002       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 2001e       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 20020       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 20021       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 20032       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 200a9       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 200c2       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 200da       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 200e2       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 200e7       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 20119       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 2014e       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 201cc       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 90001       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 90094       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 90095       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 900aa       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 90177       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 9027f       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
 9030e       1        95    8ba30efb-9aa4-4e55-8f7c-268e3dcc536b          95    2012-07-17 14:25:49
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find a valid, clear answer, so wrote some code to create 1 milion users, and add them to a single group.

On a 1vCPU, 2G RAM virtual machine running Windows Server 2008 R2, we found that :

1. **AD-LDS has no problem holding that much data**.
2. Adding a user to the directory or to the group is done in constant time, regardless of group membership size
3. ADSIEdit has a hard time listing users when the count goes over 5k. It works but the mmc.exe process consume a lot of CPU time and the whole thing slows to a crawl
4. LDP virtual list view works, but you have to tell it what you are looking for. Listing all values is too slow to work
5. [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) was stable and fast, with good support for paging.